# AIC score and purpose of logLik to compare residual variance of models

Tags: r, mixed-model, likelihood, aic

I am comparing the residual variance of two regression models, one fitted with a simple linear regression model and the other fitted with a mixed-effects model using the lme4 package. I am using the AIC test to compare the residual variance to determine whether the AIC is lower for the mixed effects model and a better fit.

```
me.model <- lmer(weight ~ weeks + (1 | person), data = data)
lm.model <- lm(weight ~ weeks + factor(person), data = data)
AIC(logLik(me.model))
AIC(logLike(lm.model))
```

I have seen the AIC test used to compare residual variance, and these include logLik. Why do you include logLik, and what does it do?

Comment: 1. AIC is a function of lok-likelihood ("how good the fit is") and of the number of model parameters. You don't need to include `logLik` in the R code because it should be called automatically, `AIC(me.model)` should work. 2. You need to be carefull when comparing AIC of model fits that come from different functions (here `lmer` and `lm`). There is no guarantee that they use the same definition of log-likelihood. 3. `person` should almost certainly be modelled as a random effect (unless you have extremely few persons). The mixed-effects model would be expected to have a lower AIC.

Comment: thanks! this is helpful, i think i'll need to dive into the difference between lmer and lm and how these functions differ

Comment: I could be wrong about this, but I believe that whereas the `lm` function just computes the log likelihood and slams that into the `AIC` function, the `lmer` function instead estimates a penalized least squares version per [this doc](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~bates/reports/MixedComp.pdf). If that is the case, their AIC scores may not be directly comparable.

Comment: One purpose of random effects models is to lower the effective degrees of freedom (number of model parameters).  So be sure whatever AIC definition is used that for the random effects model it uses the effective d.f. instead of the apparent d.f.